# is it possible to bulk import existing infrastructure in terraform?

Tags: module, terraform

i am creating infra with terraform. I have decided to modularize it. But after modularizing and using terraform plan, i can see my Plan: 28 to add, 0 to change, 28 to destroy.

If i change the existing structure to modularize will terraform destroy all? Is there any way to not delete infra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you decided to split your infrastructure code in several modules, terraform will treat your resources as a new ones, because their location did change.

> Moving resource blocks from one module into several child modules causes Terraform to see the new location as an entirely different resource.

Documentation: https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/syntax#transferring-resource-state-into-modules

There're several ways you can proceed now:

a. You can use **refactoring** feature of Terraform (available from version 1.1): https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring and utilize **moved** block to map old resources to the new ones.

b. You can start with the clean terraform state and manually import resources from your actual infrastructure to the state (https://www.terraform.io/cli/import) (you need to do it for all 28 resources)

But if its your new project, the easiest way would be to just recreate resources from scratch (of course if it's **not the production** environment containing important data)